# Will it be an terrible idea to store base64 image data as string in datastore?

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

*I am new to dealing with images/coding in general*

here is what I recieved from front end:

```py
image=self.request.POST.get('image')
image=str(image)
image = re.sub('data:image/.+;base64,', '', image)
#if i send this string back, I do get the image if i use the <img> tag
```

So is it stupid if i store it as a string property in my NDB model?

```py
class Image(ndb.Model):
    location=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    imagedata=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)#store it here
```

Comment: Why are you sending a base64-encoded image to begin with?  It's adding ~33% overhead to the size, making it difficult to stream, and wastes CPU on both ends.

Comment: So in other words, terrible idea?

Comment: Most likely, but without knowing *why* you are doing something, it's impossible to say whether it's good or bad.